# Can't remove the barrier in Brecillian Forest

Tags: dragon-age-origins

It's my first playthrough and I'm at [Nature of the Beast](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_of_the_Beast). Now I helped the Grand Oak and returned his acorn by trading it from the Mad Hermit before I even encountered the barrier.

As I understand, either the Hermit or the Oak will help you if you side with them but I seem to be locked here. The Hermit says he will help me if I kill the Oak, but I can't talk to the Oak. It only greets me and I get no dialogue options. Also, it's not hostile so I can't attack it, so now I'm stuck. Is this a bug or is there another way of removing the barrier?

Comment: sounds like a bug to me...

Comment: Yup, definitely seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. It seems that giving the acorn to the Oak made the Oak Branch appear in my inventory without me knowing. Appearently, the Oak knew beforehand that I needed it.